# Writing to File Next Line

Tags: python, file, line

I am trying to take numbers from a file, assign them a variable name, do some math on the variable, and write to the next line in the file.  If I have a file with: 1 2 3 4 5, for example, here is my abbreviated code so far (Python 3.3). The only problem I am having is writing the calculation result on the next line. Thank you in advance for your help.

```
with open('test.txt', 'r') as f:
     read_data = f.read()
     a1 = (read_data[0])`a1 = (read_data[0])
print(a1) # this is just a test to see whats happening
f.close()
with open('test.txt','w') as f:
    f.write(a1) #how do I get a1  to write on the next line of the file 
exit()
```

Comment: I think opening a file with mode `'a'` rather than `'w'` should help. That appends text to the file rather than overwriting.

Answer (score 0):

```
with open('test.txt', 'r') as f:
    data = f.read()
with open('test.txt', 'w') as f:
    for line in data.split('\n'):
        a1 = line # You didn't specify what modifications you did with the data so...
        f.write(line + '\n')
        f.write(a1 + '\n')
```

Also note that i left out `f.close()` because you don't need it.
Forgotten what it's called (another fancy word beside context manager) but `with` is a auto-closing statement, whenever you leave the block `f` will have `.close()` called by Python automatically.

Since you didn't write what sort of calulcations you want to do, here's a made up example:

```
with open('test.txt', 'r') as f:
    data = f.read()
with open('test.txt', 'w') as f:
    for line in data.split('\n'):
        a1 = int(line)*100
        f.write(line + '\n')
        f.write(str(a1) + '\n')
```

Also reading from your example you mentioned on the next line, but you didn't specify if the data was already separated by line, so taking the answer from djas you could merge these into:

```
with open('test.txt', 'r') as f:
    data = f.read()
with open('test.txt', 'w') as f:
    for line in data.split():
        a1 = int(line)*100
        f.write(line + '\n')
        f.write(str(a1) + '\n')
```

Comment: Thanks, but that put the value of a1 at the end of the first line in the file, hoping to put the value of a1 at the beginning of the next line.

Comment: @user3472574 I see, so you want to read the first line, do something, write that to the second line, then read what used to be the second line aaaand repeat? If so it would help if you showed what sort of "work" you want to have done on the line, because the above code makes no sense `a1 = (read_data[0])'a1 = ...` it's weird.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your input file looks like

```
04 80 52 67
```

, the following code works:

```
with open('input.txt', 'r') as f:
    line = f.read()

with open('output.txt','w') as f:
    for element in line.split():  
        f.write("%s\n" % ''.join(element))
```

EDIT: you can also replace `f.write("%s\n" % ''.join(element))` with `f.write(element+'\n')` and removed f.close() as suggested by @Torxed.

Comment: Also skip the `.close()` :) Since it's the whole point of `with`.

Answer (score 0):

`with open` automatically closes the file, so you can do the main logic of your program within the `with open` statement. For example, this program will do what you need:

```
with open('test.txt', 'r') as f:
  lines = f.readlines()
newlines = []
for line in lines:
  newlines.append(line)
  newline = #do some logic here
  newlines.append(newline)
with open('test.txt','w') as f:
  for line in newlines:
    f.write(line + '\n')
```

If there's only one line, you can eliminate the `for line in lines:` loop and directly modify the file instead.

On the other hand, if you want this to be an iterative process as indicated in the comments of one of these questions- that is, you want the new second line to become the new first line, and so on, you would put the above in some function as follows:

```
def func(first_line_index):
  """
  Takes the index of the current first line as first_line_index and modifies
  the next line as per your assignment, then writes it back to the file
  """
  with open('test.txt', 'r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
  line1 = lines[first_line_index]
  newlines = []
  for line in lines[:first_line_index+1]:
    newlines.append(line)
  newlines.append(lines[first_line_index])
  newline = #do some logic here based on the line above
  newlines.append(newline)
  for line in lines[first_line_index+2:]:
    newlines.append(line)
  with open('test.txt','w') as f:
    for line in newlines:
      f.write(line + '\n')

def __main__():
  counter = 0
  while #some condition- depends on your assignment:
    func(counter)
    counter += 1
```